# Costmap not published, error: Polygon lies outside map bounds, so we can't fill it

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
When i run the navigation using costmap2d, i see the laser scan in rviz, but do not see any inflated obstacles.
Rviz shows the grid cell messages are being published , and upon checking , /move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles message is published with an empy cell array:

header:
seq: 578
stamp:
secs: 1300546886
nsecs: 279417959
frame_id: odom
cell_width: 0.0500000007451
cell_height: 0.0500000007451
cells: []

Upon using rxconsole under ros.costmap2d debug mode i see this statement: Polygon lies outside map bounds, so we can't fill it.
Since no path is planned, move_base enters clear/recovery mode.
Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9489/costmap-not-published,-error:-polygon-lies-outside-map-bounds,-so-we-can%27t-fill-it/) by [hitesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/312/hitesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This likely means that the robot is not localized properly in the map. The "Polygon lies outside of map bounds" error means that the costmap is trying unsuccessfully to rasterize the footprint of the robot into a grid. This normally occurs when the robot is positioned at (0, 0) in the grid before being localized. Have you made sure to set the initial pose for AMCL using rviz as described here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack?

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0